# Outlook Category Color with Java EWS

Tags: java, exchangewebservices

I'm reading appointments with this code:

```
CalendarFolder cf=CalendarFolder.bind(service, new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, mb));
FindItemsResults<Appointment> findResults = cf.findAppointments(new CalendarView(startDate, endDate));
for (Appointment appt : findResults.getItems())
{ 
    System.out.println(appt.getSubject());
}
```

I would like to get the color of the category (not the name of it) which is selected for the appointment. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Calendar Items themselves only hold the Category Keywords, To get the colours associated with the Category Keywords you need to get the Master Category List for that mailbox and then match the Keyword to the colour eg http://www.infinitec.de/post/2011/07/28/Working-with-the-Master-Category-List%E2%80%93EWS-edition.aspx . There is documentation for the categorylist XML which lists all the possible color values in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee203806(v=exchg.80).aspx .

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Do I understand that correct? When I want to work with the colors then I first have to know the name of the category. So all need to have for holiday the same Category name and then i can match holiday to blue. And I can't say that when they have the category color blue they are holiday. Because not all are using the same language for the names.

Comment: You have to match the category keyword to what's stored in the Master CateogryList (for that Mailbox) to tell what colour is associated with the Category Keyword. This is a per Mailbox configuration Item so different users may have different colours assigned to the same keyword.

Comment: That's the problem. I dont know the keywords and i just have to look for the color, doesn't matter what keyword the use for that color..

Comment: In that case you will still need to read the colors and keywords from the Master category list to match against what you will get in the calendar appointments. This is a client driven process eg what Outlook does is first reads the Master category list and then when expands the calendar appointment when the user clicks the calendar folder it will show a colour if there is a matching keyword in Appointment. There is no color property stored on the calendar Items so you can't just search for a color that's why you need to get the associated keywords from the master list which you could then use

Comment: Thank you Glen. I think I know what to do. But in Java I don't find the MasterCategoryList and also nothing similar. Is in Java another name for it or does it not exist?

Comment: You should be able to use the UserConfiguration operation to Get/Set the XML for the master category list which I belive is in the Java API https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api/blob/master/src/main/java/microsoft/exchange/webservices/data/UserConfiguration.java You'll need to create your own code to do the Parsing or the XML or port Henning's c# example etc.

Comment: You helped me a lot. We use Exchange 07, so I need do read the file by myself. You may know the URL of the file?

Comment: In 2007 you can't use EWS to do this because in 2007 you can't access FAI (Folder Associated Items) using EWS (you can only do this in 2010 and up). You need to use WebDAV on 2007 see http://www.infinitec.de/post/2008/05/22/Working-with-the-MasterCategoryList-Via-WebDAV.aspx